# How to get managed configuration data in Android App using MDM

Tags: android, mdm, restriction, intune

I have an Android App where I want to  the `UserName` and `serverURL` to be pre-filled when device opens , Based on the device enrolment it will fetch the these values on `userName` and `serverURL` field .

Can I use Android Restriction API to get those configuration value.
like below

```
List<RestrictionEntry> restrictions =
                manager.getManifestRestrictions(Constants.PACKAGE_NAME_APP_RESTRICTION_SCHEMA);
```

It seems documents kind of vogue for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android documentation isn't perfect but at least this one about [managed configurations](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) is a bit good ;) .

> To provide externally managed configurations:

> - Declare the managed configurations in your app manifest. Doing so allows the IT admin to read the app's configurations through Google Play APIs.
> - Whenever the app resumes, use the RestrictionsManager object to check the current managed configurations, and change your app's UI and behavior to conform with those configurations.
> - Listen for the ACTION_APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED intent. When you receive this broadcast, check the RestrictionsManager to see what the current managed configurations are, and make any necessary changes to your app's behavior.

You can also check the sample projet [AppRestrictions](https://github.com/android/enterprise-samples/tree/main/AppRestrictions#readme) for more details.

Good luck